# Qual o valor default de uma variável de tipo primitivo no C#?

Tags: c#, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Quando uma variável de tipo primitivo é criada mas não inicializada o valor dela é *null*?

Exemplo:

```
public int x;
```

Se eu não fizer nada com x, ou seja não atribuir um valor a ele, ele será `null`?

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação?

Comment: Defina tipo primitivo

Comment: Isso não tem a ver com lógica de programação. Isso é um comportamento específico que depende de cada linguagem.

Comment: Cada linguagem tem um comportamento diferente para inicialização de variáveis.
Precisa especificar sobre qual linguagem você se refere.

Comment: Supondo que a tag está correta e a dúvida é sobre C#, veja aqui os valores default para cada tipo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table

Comment: Uma declaração sem valor explícito não tornará a variável usável até que um valor seja atribuído à ela no C#.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

C# não possui tipos chamados primitivos, esses tipos ditos na pergunta são por valor. O valor padrão deles costuma ser 0, cada um com sua representação de 0.

O `null` é uma referência com valor 0, então não tem um objeto associado a ele. Só tipos por referência podem ser efetivamente nulos, por isso um tipo por valor não pode ser nulo. Então um tipo por referência será nulo.

Até existem tipos que simulam nulidade, por exemplo um `int?` pode ser nulo, mas na prática é só uma composição que indica a nulidade, e tem efeitos colaterais indesejáveis.

Na construção do objeto esta variável será zerada. Em variáveis locais não compilará, é obrigatório colocar um valor, mesmo que seja o valor padrão, pode até usar `default` no lugar do valor, se for a semântica mais adequada. Desde é claro que o tipo não esteja sendo inferido.

Em C# 8 é desincentivado o uso de nulos. Ele serve muito melhor do que já é como alternativa válida para exceções em controle de fluxo (que é o mecanismo equivocado).